# Pra que serve o issue no Github?

Tags: github

No `Github` percebi que existe uma opção chamada `issue`.

Já fiz perguntas lá inclusive, mas percebi que existem algumas tags específicas para um `issue` (que não parecem ser somente para pergunta).

Afinal, pra que serve esse `issue`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Issue* no github é onde os usuários contribuem ou usuários finais da aplicação reportam os problemas/bugs encontrados. Ficando assim mais fácil a correção do problema e a obtenção das informações para simulação dos problemas.

Comment: Tive a impressão que vi uma tag lá esses dias que era como se o cara tivesse chamando gente pra ajudar em alguma coisa

Comment: provavelmente chamando para ajudar na correção de algum problema. :)

Comment: Seria correto abrir um issue sugerindo uma funcionalidade nova?

Comment: Sim, @FábioJânio. Ele recebe a tag `Feature`, como no caso desse link: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/6063

Comment: Existe inclusive um filtro, com varios `labels`, onde pode ver os tipos de `issue` que você pode abrir.

Comment: Um ponto interessante é que quando se cria um Issue, ao lado do nome é colocado um Id, exemplo #8.
Executando o commit contendo a mensagem fix #8, o commit faz como concluído o Issue.
Podendo ser usado também outras palavras chaves: closes #5

Answer (score 3):

Seria como o *stackoverflow* de cada aplicação, onde associa-se as tags para que os outros possam ajudar em seu problema, ou obtenção de informação.

Answer (score 3):

`Issues` é traduzido por `Problemas`.

`Issues`no github é uma ótima maneira de manter o controle de tarefas, melhorias e bugs para seus projetos. Eles são parecidos com um e-mail, exceto que podem ser compartilhadas e discutidas com o resto de sua equipe.

Você pode reportar bugs, erros de digitação e até mesmo uma possível solução para um problema enfrentado por uma determinada biblioteca.

Trecho traduzido dessa fonte:

https://guides.github.com/features/issues/

Answer (score 0):

Issue é um "espaço" onde é possível avisar de um bug ou defeito. Mas também é possível sugerir alguma melhoria ou nova funcionalidade. É bem útil também para quem quer contribuir com um projeto. Pode pegar uma issue e tentar ajudar/resolver.

Comment: Vinícius essa pergunta já estava solucionada "escolhida uma melhor resposta", e você deu "up" em um tópico solucionado, da próxima vez verifique se já houve uma solução escolhida antes de responder.

Comment: Não tem problema responder o que já foi respondido, mas o ideal é quando pode acrescentar algo, complementando, dando uma nova visão, uma atualização ou mesmo contestando o que foi dito.